# How to show all program which are running currently with admin permission on Windows?

Tags: windows, administrator

I'm wondering the way to show all program which are running currently with admin permission on Windows. I did google it and end up with no result. Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the [sysinternals tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021.aspx), Process Explorer, can do this.

Right-click on the column headings and add the "Integrity" column to the display. Anything running at "High" integrity or above ("System" is higher) has at least some of the admin-level group memberships or privileges.

Note that Process Explorer itself must be run as Administrator in order to collect full information.

The levels are, from most trusted to least trusted:

- System: LocalSystem account; TrustedInstaller service
- High: LocalService and NetworkServices accounts; elevated "administrator"-level accounts; administrator accounts if UAC disabled
- Medium-plus: "Accessibility" apps (e.g. on-screen keyboard). Uncommon.
- Medium: Normal authenticated user; non-elevated "administrator"-level accounts; Explorer.exe; trusted browsers (e.g. viewing "trusted" web sites)
- Low: Members only of "Everyone" and nothing else (e.g. not "Users"), Untrusted IE
- Untrusted: Anonoymous logins

If you double-click on a process and then look at the Security tab in the resulting Properties dialog, Process Explorer will show you the "security access token" of the process, which lists the specific groups to which the process belongs and the privileges that it holds. (Note that even a "disabled" privilege can still be used, the program just has to enable it.)

Looking at this info (the "security access token") is not really necessary to establish that a process is running "as administrator". But it is a worthwhile exercise to compare the access tokens of "medium" and "high" (or other) level processes that are both running under the same account. You'll notice that one of the "group" memberships is actually for the integrity level. This is of course not like the other "groups" like Administrators, etc., that you can establish for an account. It is determined automatically when processes are created.

Comment: Thank you for the "answered" mark. Keep looking, there will be additions.

Comment: Chrome uses Untrusted IL for its render-only sandboxes. It also has one Low IL process on my system; I'm not entirely sure what that one is for but it's obviously intended to be somewhat sandboxed. Possibly that's for writing to the existing Low IL folders in Windows' user accounts?